# encoding an object value within an ng-click function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, parsing

I have an ng-click calling a function as follows:

```
ng-click="vm.getTasks({status: 67})"
```

I have a series of different statuses I need to call on different elements, one of them being

```
status: 69|71
```

How do I properly parse this? The first status and others like it (2 digit numbers) work fine.

I can't just do this:

```
ng-click="vm.getTasks({status: 69|71})"
```

Comment: put the unique number on an attrib, ref the attrib in your common click event

Comment: Could you pass "status" as an array of 69 and 71? Such as { status : [ 69, 71] }. Although, I'm unsure of what control you have over the definition of getTasks() to accept an array.

Comment: No, I have no control over the API's endpoint. The endpoint is literally expecting 69|71 .

Comment: pass it as string (`{status: '69|71'}`). Otherwise it will become bitwise ORing.

Answer (score 4):

ng-click parameter is evaluted as javascript

```
67 is valid JS number type
```

but

```
69|71
```

is expression 69 "Bitwise OR assignment" 71. In this case result is 71.

If you want pass multiple numbers, is must be valid javascript representation

Ideally array

```
[69, 71]
```

or other valid expression for example string

```
"69|71"
```

Answer (score 0):

In your template:

```
ng-click="vm.getTasks({status: [69, 71]})"
```

In your controller:

```
$scope.vm.getTasks = function(obj) {
    var encoded = '';
    angular.forEach(obj.status, function(value, key) {
        if (key === 0) {
            encoded = encoded + value
        } else {
            encoded = encoded + '|' + value;
        }
    });

    // make call to backend using encoded
}
```

I personally like this a bit more because it hides the fact that the server is expecting something weird and lets you more obviously express the fact that there are multiple statuses to other devs. But you could also use the string approach as indicated above

Comment: i think `obj.status.join('|')` is better solution